# Dump PostgreSQL database in docker container using Celery

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, celery

I use FastAPI framework and would like to create a periodic Celery task to dump the database. My test project:

- docker-compose.yaml
- Dockerfile
- requirements.txt
- main.py
- tasks.py

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgr
    image: postgres:15.1-alpine
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: "dbase"
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
  site:
    container_name: test-site
    build:
      context: .
    command: uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  redis:
    container_name: test-redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
  celery:
    container_name: test-celery
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A tasks worker -B --loglevel=INFO
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
COPY . .
```

requirements.txt

```
celery==5.2.3
fastapi==0.89.1
redis==4.4.2
uvicorn==0.20.0
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def get():
    return {"site": "ok"}
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery

celery_app = Celery(
    "worker",
    broker='redis://redis',
    backend="rpc://",
)

@celery_app.on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(1.0, dump_dbase.s(), name='task 1')    

@celery_app.task
def dump_dbase():
    #Some code to dump database in "potgr" container
    pass
```

So I need to paste some code into the dump_dbase() function.

This task is easy to do manually from the postgr container. The command looks something like this:

*pg_dump -U postgres dbase > 1.dump*

But how to do it from a Celery task? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should be able to run pretty much the same command using the `subprocess` module; `pg_dump` takes command-line options that can point at a "remote" database.  Can you build this setup in a normal Python virtual environment, then try to adapt it to the container setup?

Comment: I tried to dump database from my local machine pg_dump -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres dbase > dbase.dump. It works. In order to run subprocess or os.system module I think it is necessary to install postgresql in the "celery" container, something like "RUN apt install postgresql" in Dockerfile, after wich the "pg_dump" command will be available in the "celery" container. I am not very experienced in docker. I try. I think this could work.